# SQL Conditional Aggregation with FILTER on Linked Table Values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a survey application where users answer questions about their activities. General Activities are in `ACTIVITIES_T`, General Questions are in `QUESTIONS_T`, and the specific Activity Questions are in `ACTIVITY_QUESTIONS_T`. Answers are stored in `ANSWERS_T` for a specific `ACTIVITY_QUESTION_ID`.

Among general questions, `QUESTION_T ID = 1` is the Start Time Question and `QUESTION_T ID = 2` the is End Time Question. These are always used in specific `ACTIVITY_QUESTION`s and paired with an activity. For these Date answers, the values are recorded in the `ANSWERS_T`  Date Answer column `answer_date_val`.

I'm trying to get the Total Duration of user-entered activities as follows, and this is working OK (this is Postgres),

```
(SELECT 
        SUM ( 
                (extract (epoch from ans2.answer_date_val) - extract (epoch from ans1.answer_date_val)
            ) 
            FILTER (WHERE aq1.question_id = 1 and aq2.question_id = 2) --Conditional Aggregation
FROM   study_t s
       INNER JOIN recalls_t r
               ON u.id = r.user_id
       left JOIN PUBLIC.events_t e 
               ON ( r.id = e.recall_id )
       left JOIN PUBLIC.answers_t ans1  
               ON (ans1.event_id = e.id)
       left JOIN PUBLIC.answers_t ans2  
               ON (ans2.event_id = e.id)               
       left JOIN PUBLIC.activity_questions_t aq1 
               ON (ans1.activity_question_id = aq1.id)
       left JOIN PUBLIC.activity_questions_t aq2 
               ON (ans2.activity_question_id = aq2.id)      
WHERE s.id = ...
```

But what I'm wondering is, is it necessary to do a Dual Join on `ANSWERS_T` and `ACTIVITY_QUESTIONS_T` (`aq1/aq2`,`ans1/ans2`)? Could I have gotten my Sum-with-Filter from a single Join on these tables? I need 2 separate Answer values, and then I need to sum up their minuses. It sounds like they should be independent, which is why I went with a Dual Join.

Comment: What is a "Dual Join"?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: I mean that I'm selecting from `ANSWERS_T` and `ACTIVITY_QUESTIONS_T` **twice**. The question is, is it possible to avoid that and have a single Join on these tables.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. I'm summing up the difference between ANS2.value and ANS1.value (per Event) to get the total duration of the Recal. These are separate values. To get the 2nd Answer/AQ I do an additional join on the same two tables, and then I'm able to do the subtraction. The question is, is it necessary to have these tables joined twice. This action is introducing extra duplicated rows into my final resultset, and the SUM FILTER is no longer correct.